# If condition for a table in geodatabase in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I want to do what would be in a dataframe:

```
if df['col'] = 1:
    do this..
```

but for a table in a geodatabase:

```
if col = 1  in arcpy.ListTables("qt"):
   do this..
```

**Purpose**:

For the rows that have in column 'col' the value 1 in a table in a geodatabase  do a piece of code.

How to do this in ArcPy?

**Update**

sample table:

```
names  col
A       0
B       1
C       1
D       0
E       1
```

the block of code after the condition check, therefore should be implemented in rows B,C,E.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what exactly do you want to do? Try `if col in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("qt")]`

Comment: @BERA I have updated the question.

Comment: You want to check if column name is 1 or if the entry in column has the value of 1

Comment: For the rows that have in column 'col' the value 1 do the piece of code.So the second sentence you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [da.SearchCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\feature'
field = 'somecolumn'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field) as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      if row[0]==1:
         #do something
```

Comment: shouldn't it be row[1] == 1?

Comment: No index starts with 0, so 0 = first field (only field in this example). It is common to have many fields as a list as input to the searchcursor.